# .or query in parse unity crashes on iOS

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, parse-platform

I'm doing a .or query which in every platform works fine except in iOS.
As soon it reaches the line where it does the .or, it crashes with:

System.Collections.Generic.List> doesn't implement interface System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable>

- Assertion: should not be reached at mini-trampolines.c:183

Here's the code:

var isChallenger = ParseObject.GetQuery("Match")
            .WhereEqualTo("Challenger",fb.loggedUser);

```
    var isChallenged = ParseObject.GetQuery("Match")
        .WhereEqualTo("Challenged",fb.loggedUser);

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = isChallenger.Or (isChallenged); // Crashes here.
```

I'm doing it just like in the docs, not sure what's wrong.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks,

Pablo

Comment: This might be a stripping error. What stripping level are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug I reported here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/750897958275392/

Except, I only saw this bug when using ParseQuery. The workaround I used is to use ParseQuery only, but I see you're already doing that. Is the code you posted exactly the same as the code you're actually using?